# How to find maximum velocity of an image of an object excecuting a SHM in front of a concave mirror?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, geometric-optics

> I was doing a problem in which a block of mass of 1 kg attached to a spring of spring constant 100 N/m excecutes a SHM with the blocks equilibrium position at the centre of curvature of a concave mirror of focal length 20 cm placed in front of the oscillating block, and the maximum displacement of block from equilibrium position ( centre of curvature of mirror) is 5 millimeter.It is asked to find the maximum velocity of the oscillating image.
> [image]

Now I know velocity of image  $\mathsf v_i=-\frac{f^2}{(X_o-f)^2}v_o$

f-focal length  ,    m-mass of block

k-spring constant  ,  t-time

$X_o$-displacement of block

$v_o$-velocity of block

And I derived the equation for position of block with respect to the pole of mirror as $X_o = \frac {5}{10}sin \left(\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\right)t\right)-40$

And velocity of block as $v_o = \frac {5}{10}\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}cos \left(\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\right)t\right)$

Now i don't know how to find the maximum value of this $\mathsf v_i=-\frac{f^2}{(X_o-f)^2}v_o$ and

i am stuck here and don't know how to proceed further.Can someone show me how to proceed further.